# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<SID> State value meaning

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<SID>` contains a value called `State` which is a bit mask `DWORD`.

All information I could find about it is this:

```
001 = PROFILE_MANDATORY
Profile is mandatory.

002 = PROFILE_USE_CACHE
Update locally Cached profile.

004 = PROFILE_NEW_LOCAL
Using a new local profile.

008 = PROFILE_NEW_CENTRAL
Using a new central profile.

010 = PROFILE_UPDATE_CENTRAL
Need to update central profile.

020 = PROFILE_DELETE_CACHE
Need to delete cached profile.

040 = PROFILE_UPGRADE
Need to upgrade profile.

080 = PROFILE_GUEST_USER
Using guest user profile.

100 = PROFILE_ADMIN_USER
Using administrator profile.

200 = DEFAULT_NET_READY
Default net profile is available & ready.

400 = PROFILE_SLOW_LINK
Identified slow network link.

800 = PROFILE_TEMP_ASSIGNED
Temporary profile loaded.
```

But exactly what do those values mean?! I've seen a non-administrator account with `State = 100` for example.

Does `State = 4` only appear when a user logged in for the first time and their profile got created, changing to a different state on 2nd login?

Will a `State = 2` appear if a user is not using roaming profiles? What will be the value of `State` when a user is using a roaming profile that just got copied from the server?!

What exactly does `State = 200` mean??

So many questions, because this information really seems to not be great.

Also that list appears to be missing at least one value, as I found a `State = 8000` on a few users.

Does anyone happen to know exactly what these values mean??

Comment: Are those bitvectors in octal? (Sorry, hex.)

Comment: @Neil Hex, sorry I didn't include it

Comment: That's not a programming question. It is off-topic.

Comment: @IInspectable that's debatable - without programming knowledge how can anyone accurately answer this question? I could include the `profile.c` source code if that makes it any more programming related for you :)

Comment: That's like saying that a user wouldn't be able to use calc.exe without programming knowledge. Now clearly, that is bogus. Documentation is frequently accessible to non-developers.

Comment: @IInspectable true, but knowledge about how calc.exe works behind the scenes when you press this key and that key together (from a programming point of view, not mathematical point of view) is probably lost to a non-programmer... So while you could argue that the question has nothing to do with .NET... it's clearly got to do with programming.

Comment: *"How do I read a registry key/value/data?"* is a programming question. *"How do I interpret random registry keys/values/data?"* is not a programming question. You are asking about the latter. Clearly not a programming question. And clearly not *at all* related to .NET nor C#. You'll find those registry entries in systems that don't even have .NET installed.

Comment: @IInspectable so your logic is that asking "does anyone have know how I should interpret these values created by a program by a set or programmers using programming logic" have nothing to do with programming... Interesting. Then neither should a question about how do I read a file have anything to do with programming because there are multiple ways of doing it and depending on your needs (line by line, char by char, byte by byte, different encodings, etc) there might be multiple right answers which really depend on the perspective of the person looking at it.

Comment: And perhaps more importantly, here's the interesting fact - "how do I read a file/registry key/value/data" is something that can totally be answered by a non-programmer by just reading the documentation you just highlighted is available to everyone. So how is that considered a programming question and this isn't? You want to have a go at it not being a .NET/C# question fine, but don't try to convince me it's not a programming question... Also clearly the possible values from this registry key are as random as the letters "H e l  l o" in Hello World.

Comment: Time to take the [tour], since you forgot to do so it seems. Also might want to read through [help/on-topic]. If you find that you have a valid point and I'm just too thick to get it, take it to meta and ask for confirmation.

Comment: @IInspectable if you really want to, I could just rephrase the question by pointing it at the leaked Windows source code and basically just ask if someone could explain under which circumstances each of the flags gets set... It's exactly the same question, just phrased under a "can someone explain this code" title... Normally I'd say that's getting really pedantic but I think we're past that stage honestly.

Comment: *"Can someone explain this code?"* is not a programming question. *"How does this code construct work?"* is. You see the difference? If not, revisit the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Perhaps superuser could answer?

Comment: Where did you find those values? I was unable to find this in the SDK or elsewhere via web search. This seems to be the only place where this information can be found with those symbol names. Correction, there's a mention in [profile.c](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/master/dll/win32/userenv/profile.c) from ReactOS.